# Cisco ASA 5505 - Access to DMZ with one public IP

Tags: cisco-asa, dmz

I am trying to configure my Cisco ASA 5505 firewall to allow access from the internet to DMZ web and mail server. I'm new to the Cisco world so excuse me if this is a newbie question. I know that this subject has been covered on many sites, but most of them assume that you have more than one public IP address. My situation is that I only have one public IP address and therefore have to use a PAT configuration I believe.

This is my setup: My ASA (with a basic license) is configured with three interfaces for the inside, outside and dmz zones. There are two servers in my dmz - one web and one mail server.

I believe I have checked my configuration against various sites on the internet, but still I can't figure out how to get it right. This is my running config:

```
...  
ASA Version 9.0(4)26  
...  
!  
interface Ethernet0/0  
switchport access vlan 2  
!  
interface Ethernet0/1  
switchport access vlan 3  
!  
interface Ethernet0/2  
switchport access vlan 3  
!  
interface Ethernet0/3  
switchport access vlan 3  
!  
interface Ethernet0/4  
switchport access vlan 1  
!  
interface Ethernet0/5  
switchport access vlan 1  
!  
interface Ethernet0/6  
switchport access vlan 1  
!  
interface Ethernet0/7  
switchport access vlan 1  
!  
interface Vlan1  
  nameif inside  
  security-level 100  
  ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0   
!  
interface Vlan2  
  nameif outside  
  security-level 0  
  ip address 109.198.xxx.yyy 255.0.0.0 
!  
interface Vlan3  
  no forward interface Vlan1  
  nameif dmz  
  security-level 50  
  ip address 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.0  
!  
ftp mode passive  
dns server-group DefaultDNS  
domain-name mydomain.dk  
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface  
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface  
!  
object network obj_any  
  subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0  
!  
object network inside-subnet  
  subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.25 5.0  
!  
object network dmz-subnet  
  subnet 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0  
!  
object network hst-mail-server  
  host 172.16.1.11  
  description Mail server in DMZ  
!  
object network hst-web-server  
  host 172.16.1.10  
  description Web server in DMZ  
!  
object network hst-web-dns  
  host 172.16.1.10  
  description Web dmz host DNS  
!  
object network hst-web-http  
  host 172.16.1.10  
  description Web dmz host HTTP  
!  
object network hst-web-https  
  host 172.16.1.10  
  description Web dmz host HTTPS  
!  
object-group service web-services tcp  
  port-object eq www  
  port-object eq https  
!  
object-group service mail-services tcp  
  port-object eq smtp  
  port-object eq 587  
  port-object eq 993  
  port-object eq 4190  
!  
object-group service svcgrp-web-udp udp  
  port-object eq dnsix  
!  
object-group service svcgrp-web-tcp tcp  
  port-object eq www  
  port-object eq https  
!  
object-group network RFC1918  
  network-object 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0  
  network-object 172.16.0.0 255.240.0.0  
  network-object 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0  
!  
object-group service svcgrp-mail-tcp tcp  
  port-object eq smtp  
!  
access-list outside_access_in extended deny ip any object-group RFC1918   
access-list outside_access_in extended permit udp any object hst-web-server object-group svcgrp-web-udp  
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any object hst-web-server object-group svcgrp-web-tcp  
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any object hst-mail-server object-group svcgrp-mail-tcp  
access-list outside_access_in extended permit ip any any  
...  
!  
object network obj_any  
  nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface  
object network inside-subnet  
  nat (inside,dmz) dynamic interface  
object network dmz-subnet  
  nat (dmz,outside) dynamic interface  
object network hst-web-dns  
  nat (dmz,outside) static interface service udp dnsix dnsix  
object network hst-web-http  
  nat (dmz,outside) static interface service tcp www www  
object network hst-web-https  
  nat (dmz,outside) static interface service tcp https https  
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside  
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 109.198.xxx.zzz 1 
...
```

Comment: Did you look at https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/115904-asa-config-dmz-00.html#anc12

Comment: Yes, I have read it - but it describe a scenario with more than one public IP address (NAT).

Comment: How does it not...

Comment: Hmm, I can't see other vice. If you try to execute the nat command it give you an error: ERROR: Address 109.198.xxx.yyy overlaps with outside interface address.
ERROR: NAT Policy is not downloaded

Comment: Afaik in that instance you'd use the ifname

Comment: This is the nat command I have used: nat (dmz,outside) static interface service tcp www www. Is that wrong?

Comment: It's (outside, dmz) from what I remember, source, dest

Comment: I don't think it matters. The command is bidirectional as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working - it was a wrong configured acl to deny access to rfc1918 subnets from the outside.
By the way: I found an interesting article about denying access to the all subnets in rfc3330, not just only the private ones in rfc1918: https://techbloc.net/archives/1392
Inspired by that I have enhanced my configuration a bit. This is the new definition of subnets to deny access to:

```
object-group network rfc3330-subnets  
  description Group of all rfc3330 subnets incl private and special use  
  network-object 0.0.0.0 255.0.0.0  
  network-object 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0  
  network-object 14.0.0.0 255.0.0.0  
  network-object 24.0.0.0 255.0.0.0  
  network-object 39.0.0.0 255.0.0.0  
  network-object 127.0.0.0 255.0.0.0  
  network-object 128.0.0.0 255.255.0.0  
  network-object 169.254.0.0 255.255.0.0  
  network-object 172.16.0.0 255.240.0.0  
  network-object 191.255.0.0 255.255.0.0  
  network-object 192.0.0.0 255.255.255.0  
  network-object 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0  
  network-object 192.88.99.0 255.255.255.0  
  network-object 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0  
  network-object 198.18.0.0 255.254.0.0  
  network-object 223.255.255.0 255.255.255.0  
  network-object 224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0  
  network-object 240.0.0.0 240.0.0.0
```

And this is my new acl definitions:

```
access-list outside_access_in extended deny ip object-group rfc3330-subnets any  
access-list outside_access_in extended permit udp any object hst-web-server object-group svcgrp-web-udp  
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any object hst-web-server object-group svcgrp-web-tcp  
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any object hst-mail-server object-group svcgrp-mail-tcp  
access-list outside_access_in extended permit ip any any
```